# Change Grid Visibility property with ToggleButton in pure XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visibility

I have a Grid named `comSection` which i want to set the visibility with a ToggleButton :

unchecked = collapsed

checked = visible

The Grid and the ToggleButton are inside a `DataTemplate` and a `ListBox`

I had a lot of trouble trying to access the visibility in C# :

```
comSection.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; //can't access this way
```

Using `PropertyChangedEventHandler` i can't get it to work

So i wonder if it is possible to bind visibility in pure XAML. Maybe using `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

---

**EDIT** My XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="71*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="580*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="IssueList" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Issues, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="grd">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- Other code here -->


                        <!-- The ToggleButton -->
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="comSecButton" Width="10" Height="10" Click="comSection.Visibility = Collapsed" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibleConverter}}">

                        </ToggleButton>

                        <!-- The Grid I want to show/hide -->
                        <Grid x:Name="comSection" Visibility="{Binding comSec_Click, Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibleConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">

                            <TextBox x:Name="comment" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="148" />
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: If you post your xaml and code, then somebody should be able to help you. There are multiple ways of doing it, it should be simple, The converter you mentioned should also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DataTrigger in a Style for the Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="comSection" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=comSecButton}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    ...
</Grid>
```